# Linux Azure Web App initial request has very slow response time

Tags: azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

I don’t have any experience with web deployment so there will definitely be gaps in my knowledge, so I do apologise. I am creating a Flask web app that uses the OpenAI API that basically allows users to converse with the bot and save the conversation into the database.
I am puzzled why doing a POST request to the web server can result in the server taking 2-5 minutes to respond. The most confusing part of this is that only the INITIAL request is dreadfully slow. After the request is returned, the web application functions as normal, having acceptable response timings.

Testing it locally on the machine no issues are present, yet deployed in production it displays very slow response times with the initial request. I don’t believe it is the API at fault, after testing. I think the issue either lies in the library I am using ‘flask-turbo’ (might behave differently when deployed) or how I have configured the Linux web application.

I have configured the web app to ‘Always On’ and tried tweaking the HTTP version and ARR affinity with no success. I have Scaled Up (Basic B1) and Scaled Out (3 instances) the application with no success as well. Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

*app.py* code.

```py
conversation_history = []
@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])  # this sets the route to this page
def chat_page():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'submit-input-button' in request.form:
            input_text = request.form.get("input-prompt")
            if turbo.can_stream() and input_text.strip():
                # Tracking chat conversation and posting to API
                chat_response = get_chatgpt_response(conversation_history)
                conversation_history.append(chat_response)

                return turbo.stream([turbo.append("> " + input_text + "\n" + chat_response + "\n\n", 'output-text'), turbo.update('', 'input_error_text'), turbo.update('', 'database_error_text')])
            else:
                return turbo.stream([turbo.update('Please enter an input', 'input_error_text'), turbo.update('', 'database_error_text')])
        elif 'submit-answers-button' in request.form:
            # Submitting text from the output window to the database
            output_text = request.form.get("output-text")
            title_num = request.form.get("scenario-num")

            if post_to_database(title_num, output_text):
                return turbo.stream([turbo.update('Successfully posted to database!', 'database_error_text')])
            else:
                return turbo.stream([turbo.update('Error: Unable to post to the database', 'database_error_text')])

    return render_template("index.html", input_error_text="", database_error_text="", scenario_num=key, scenario_title=scenario_obj["title"], scenario_desc=scenario_obj["desc"])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

*index.html* code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}" />
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/styles.css" /> -->
    {{ turbo() }}
    <title>ChatGPT Web App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div id="main-heading" class="main-container match-bg-color">
        <h1>ChatGPT Test</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="scenario-section" class="main-container match-bg-color">
        <h2 id="scenario-heading">Scenario {{ scenario_num }} - {{ scenario_title }}</h2>
        <p id="scenario-description">{{ scenario_desc }}</p>
      </div>
      <form method="post" id="chat-bot-form">
        <!-- Input makes it possible to retrieve the scenario number -->
        <input type="text" name="scenario-num" value="{{ scenario_num }}" hidden />
        <div id="output-container" class="main-container">
          <label for="output-text" class="main-label">Output</label>
          <textarea
            name="output-text"
            id="output-text"
            class="text-box"
            rows="18"
            readonly
          >
{{ output_text }}</textarea
          >
        </div>
        <div id="input-container" class="main-container">
          <label for="input-prompt" class="main-label">Input</label>
          <textarea
            name="input-prompt"
            id="input-prompt"
            class="text-box"
            rows="5"
            placeholder="Enter your prompt here..."
          ></textarea>
          <div class="input-button-container">
            <button type="submit" id="submit-input" name="submit-input-button"
              >Enter</button
            >
            <p class="bold-text warning-text" id="input_error_text">{{custom_text}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main-container match-bg-color" id="submit-answers-container">
          <button id="submit-answers-button" name="submit-answers-button"
            >Submit Your Answers</button
          >
          <p class="bold-text warning-text" id="database_error_text">{{custom_text}}</p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </main>
    <script>
      // Automatically scrolls text down
      let textarea = document.getElementById("output-text");
      textarea.addEventListener("selectionchange", function () {
        console.log("Scroll down man");
        textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** Added code. However *app.py* needed to have some code removed and modified (such as API call) due to maintaining academic integrity. *index.html* is unmodified. I should also point out this also my first time using Flask.

Comment: Please share the code that which you tried.

Comment: I have added code to my question. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

- Consider using a production-ready WSGI server like Gunicorn or uWSGI instead of the built-in Flask development server. These servers are designed for production use and often offer better performance and stability.

**gunicorn_config.py:**

```py
# gunicorn_config.py

import multiprocessing

# Bind to the IP and port where your application should listen.
bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"  # Replace with your desired IP and port.

# Number of Gunicorn worker processes to spawn.
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1  # Adjust as needed based on your server's resources.

# Set the worker class to use. 'gevent' and 'eventlet' are alternative worker classes
# that can be more efficient for I/O-bound applications. The default is 'sync'.
worker_class = "sync"

# Number of worker threads per worker process. Adjust as needed.
threads = 2

# Specify your Flask application's entry point (usually the app variable in your app.py).
# Replace 'app_name' with your actual application's name.
# You can also specify the Python module that contains your app using the syntax 'module:app'.
app = "app_name:app"

# Enable or disable daemon mode. Daemon mode runs Gunicorn in the background.
daemon = False

# Set the location of Gunicorn's error log.
errorlog = "/var/log/gunicorn/error.log"  # Adjust the path as needed.

# Set the location of Gunicorn's access log.
accesslog = "/var/log/gunicorn/access.log"  # Adjust the path as needed.

# Enable access log format. Common options are "combined", "common", "short", and "tiny".
# You can also specify your custom log format.
access_log_format = "%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s \"%(r)s\" %(s)s %(b)s \"%(f)s\" \"%(a)s\""

# Configure the maximum number of requests a worker will process before restarting.
max_requests = 1000

# Configure the maximum number of requests a worker will process before graceful restart.
max_requests_jitter = 50

# Set the timeout for requests (in seconds). Adjust as needed.
timeout = 60

# Enable keep-alive connections.
keepalive = 2

# Set the maximum number of headers that the server will accept.
max_request_header_size = 8192

# Set the maximum size of the request body.
max_request_body_size = 1048576  # 1 MB

# Preload the application before the worker processes are forked.
preload_app = True

# Disable worker process auto-reloading.
reload = False
```

Please check how to update [gunicorn](https://azureossd.github.io/2022/08/03/Gunicorn-update-HTTP-headers-On-Azure-App-Service/) HTTP Headers on Azure App Service for reference.

**Response time:**

[image]

Comment: I've followed your answer and when deploying to the server I'm getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '–bind=0'`. I have added gunicorn as a module in the requirements.txt so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: @Programmer367 You are trying to run Gunicorn with the -bind=0 argument, which is not a valid argument for Gunicorn. The bind configuration should be specified in the Gunicorn configuration file (gunicorn_config.py in the example provided) rather than as a command-line argument.